# Further question with memory mapped interface

Tags: c, memory-mapping

I still have some issues with my c code that deals with an memory mapped device.
At the moment I declare the address space for the registers I write as volatile
pointer and I write data to them as shown below:

```
volatile unsigned int *wr_register = (int *) 0x40000000;
volatile unsigned int *c_register =  (int *) 0x40000100;
...

main{

  *wr_register = 0x01234567;

  *c_register = 0x01234567;    
  *(c_register+1) = 0x89abcdef;  

}
```

This works more or less fine. However, I would like to have specific read and
write functions that interact with the memory mapped registers. So ideally,
it would look something like this:

```
const unsigned int wr_register = 0x40000000;
const unsigned int c_register  = 0x40000100;

function write_REG(unsigned int address, int offset, int data)
{
    (unsigned int*) (address + offset) = data;
}

main{

  *write_REG(0x40000000, 0, 0x01234567);

  *write_REG(0x40000100, 0, 0x01234567);
  *write_REG(0x40000100, 1, 0x89abcdef);  

}
```

I have not tried it out yet to be honest, but I am wondering if somebody could
tell me if this is a proper way to do it?

EDIT: Maybe it is of use for someone else, here I have my function and they seem to work. Many thanks for the helpful comments!

```
void reg_write(unsigned int address, int offset, int data)
{
    *((volatile unsigned int*)address + offset) = data;
}

int reg_read(unsigned int address, int offset)
{
    return(*((volatile unsigned int*)address + offset));
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: I think you have extraneous '*' before you function calls. Also, I think you intended to use the variable "addresses" in your function calls instead of hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your code:

1. I assume you meant `void` where you wrote `function`.
2. You should make the pointer inside the function to be `volatile` as well.
3. You should dereference the pointer before writing the data. The `*` should be inside the function, not at the call site (`*write_REG`) as it is now - that would be a compile error.
4. You should add the offset to the pointer, not the address. This is because an offset of 1 is meant to be the next `int` which could be, say, 4 bytes away, but adding it to the address will only add 1 byte.

Your corrected function should look like this:

```
void write_REG(unsigned int address, int offset, int data)
{
    *((volatile unsigned int*)address + offset) = data;
}
```

and you would call it like:

```
write_REG(0x40000000, 0, 0x01234567);
```

Comment: Yes, I meant void instead of function ;). Very good point with making sure that I add the offset to the pointer rather the address itself! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That would be just fine IMHO. I sometimes use macros like:

```
#define WR_REG     *(volatile unsigned int*)0x40000000
```

This allows the registers to be used sort of like variables:

```
WR_REG = 0x12345678;
```

Comment: They are variables. Poster's original code is pretty much the correct way of doing things, I don't know why she wants to make it more complicated.