# Unhandled exception at 0x00c71443 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000028

Tags: c

I was writing C code to simulate transmitting a character from uart. I am getting the title error.

### Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void transmit(char uart, char data[]){
   writeReg(uart,data);
      ......
       ......
}

void writeReg(char addr, char data[]){
  char* dataPtr = data;
  char* regPtr = (char*)addr;
  *regPtr = *dataPtr;  ........ This is where the error was thrown <bad ptr>
}

void main(){
   transmit(0x28,"1245");
}
```

Comment: The `addr` argument has type `char`. Is this intentional? It appears dubious.

Comment: You told it to write to memory address 0x28,and it told you you can't do that. That should be a hint

Comment: addr denotes 8 bit address  and hence the data type char.

Comment: I wanted to declare some address location representing a memory mapped register interface. Basically I am trying to send data to a target through memory mapped register interface. Target address is 8 bit. 0xx28 hexadecimal thus 8 bits. I want to implement transmit function and test it without a target hardware. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Your code attempts to write to memory at the location `0x00000028`. This address is in a protected region of the address space and you are not allowed to write (or read) there. Hence the access violation.

Your problems begin here:

```
char* regPtr = (char*)addr;
```

`addr` is a char, and in your program it has the value `0x28`. You then treat that as an address, and the inevitable consequence is the access violation.

The reason the compiler rejected

```
char* regPtr = addr;
```

is that `addr` is not a `char*`. Simply casting does not change that fact. When you are faced with a compilation error that you do not understand, do not attempt to cast your way past it. Step 1 is always to understand the error.

Your code makes no real sense. I don't know what it tries to do, so I cannot tell you what the code should be.

Comment: +1 particularly for the advice about casting.  If your types don't match up, and you don't know why, it's probably an error.  Casting just lets you blithely ignore that error til it either blows up in your face or evolves into a whole unholy mess of casts.

Comment: Thanks. The error was thrown while executing the code. if I dont type cast it. I could not get addr value as 8 bit address. I referred this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166201/further-question-with-memory-mapped-interface

Comment: I don't think you really understand my comment about the cast. The cast doesn't make your code any more valid. It just converts a compile time error into a runtime error. You cannot write to 0x28. Not in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a character value to a pointer, which gives you an invalid pointer.

Perhaps you wanted to do this instead?

```
char *regPtr = &addr;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP is trying to write into `addr`. `addr` does indeed contain some kind of address; just not a memory address.

Comment: @ikegami `regPtr` is initialized to the value of `addr`, then dereferenced on the LHS - that facilitates writing to `addr` in my book.

Comment: Why are you telling me your post shows to facilitate doing something the OP doesn't want to do?

Comment: Ah, misunderstanding - I wasn't trying to infer an intention beyond what I suggested, since I don't clearly see what that is. You're right that there *probably* is one, but the question hardly makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write in the `memory location` that is **not** allocated to your program.

*Your program must change values in memory contained only to the address space allocated to it.*

Allocation of address space is done **dynamically** and you should always use **relative** memory location and not **absolute** location, like in your case. Because relative memory location will shift according to the address space allocated to your program, but absolute location

> may or may not fall

in it, which may produce `exceptions` like it did.

Comment: To be clear, there are cases where absolute addresses make sense -- in an OS kernel, for example, you own the whole machine, so you can put stuff wherever you like.  And some system stuff is at well-known addresses.  But if you're building a kernel, you probably also understand pointers really, really well.  :)  So you know when the rules may be broken.

Comment: That is true :) . But what i mentioned above are just the guidelines.