# Pointer to volatile data (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000))

Tags: c++, c, arm

I am analyzing a peripheral driver's files and found some register mapping code. I have basic knowledge about pointers, but am unable to understand the below code.

```
#define WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R        (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000))
```

I have understood that it defines the identifier `WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R` to the register's memory address. But I am not able to understand the syntax on the right side. Could anyone explain me in detail why this pointer is written in such a way?

Comment: What don't you understand specifically the `0x40000000` or what `volatile uint32_t *` means?

Comment: Please chose one of the `C` and `C++` tags, unless you're asking specifically about an interaction between these two languages.

Comment: You might also benefit from reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4166201/212858) which ends up with similar code.

Comment: Possible duplicate [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267001/how-to-store-a-variable-at-a-specific-memory-location/15268780#15268780) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029938/c-pointers-and-the-physical-address/5031056#5031056) and [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262865/what-does-port-0x41004400ul-mean-here/31266754#31266754). And so on. Please do some research.

Comment: @Lundin I choose 2 here as coming closest to resemble. Well, to be fair it might be hard to find these dupes, unless you have answered them yourselves ;-) ...

Comment: If i tell frankly in simple words than i am not able to understand why there is two '*' in right-side statement? I mean we are declaring a pointer to that particular memory address like `volatile uint32_t *ptr = 0x40000000`. What is the purpose of another pointer?

Comment: @DombleMaza To clarify finally: The outer `*` is not _a pointer_, but used to dereference that formerly declared (casted) pointer, thus the memory address is accessed to read/write a value from/to it.

Comment: The purpose is to use that macro as: `WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R= 0xAA55AA55` or `uint32_t reg_value = WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R;` In other words you directly access the content of the resister to set or read it.

Answer (score 23):

Let's take it one step at the time:

```
0x40000000
```

is your memory address.

```
(uint32_t *)0x40000000
```

casts this to a pointer to that memory address, of type `uint32_t`, meaning 32 bit without sign.

```
(volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000
```

`volatile` means, basically, "hey compiler, don't do any optimization; I really want to go every time to that memory address and fetch it, without any prefetch or anything particular".

```
*((volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000)
```

means: take the value contained at the address identified by that pointer, so the four bytes starting at `0x40000000`.

Comment: @DombleMaza refering to your comment: which "following syntax" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i am still not able to understand the purpose of making this whole this as a pointer. `(volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000` is not a pointer itself?

May i write a same code as `volatile uint32_t *ptr = 0x40000000; #define WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R     *ptr `?

Answer (score 9):

Analyzing `(*((volatile uint32_t *)0x40000000))`

- `0x40000000` is the address of register in your micro memory map
- the register is 32 bits wide, that means must be `uint32_t *`
- `volatile` is added to tell compile to avoid to optimize that variable because of could change, for example, in an interrupt routine.
- last: the `*` dereference the pointer: make you able to access the content of that specific register.

Comment: Note also the dereference. Assigning this definition to an integer will load the value at the address.

Comment: @TruthSerum True, I edited. I was hoping that OP understand that on his/her own, at least.